# How to setState without using .bind(this) in react-native?

Tags: react-native, setstate

I have no idea How to set state.
Below is my code...

```
import React from 'react';
import { StyleSheet, Text, View, TouchableHighlight, AsyncStorage, ListView } from 'react-native';

export default class App extends React.Component {

    constructor(){
        super();
        this.state = {
            myLeader: 'Joe',
        };
    }

    setMyLeader(name){
        this.setState({
            myLeader: name
        });
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <View>
                <TouchableHighlight

                    style={{padding: 30}}
                    onPress={this.setState(myLeader: 'xxx')}
                >
                    <Text>foo</Text>
                </TouchableHighlight>
            </View>
        );
    }
}
```

error message is this. 'Can't find variable: myLeader'

How to fix this problem?

Comment: onPress={() => this.setMyLeader('xxx')} // it worked

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Inside your onPress function you can:

a) directly set the state

```
onPress={() => this.setState({ myLeader: 'xxx' })}
```

b) call your setLeader function

```
onPress={() => this.setMyLeader('xxx')}
```

Comment: @sonicmario could you please mark my answer as correct? Just click on the check icon beside my answer! Thank you

Comment: Your anser is awesome, but I can't mark your answer.
Votes cast by those with less than 15 reputation are recorded, but do not change the publicly displayed post score